# Winforms combobox compare

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Am using two combobox in my C# .net windows application like combobox1 & combobox2(two combobox contain same items) if am choosing any items in combobox1  i need to hide that value in combobox2.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Perhaps you could provide some code to help us find the problem?

Comment: You want to hide it or you want to remove it ?

Comment: Lawrance, are you trying to make a 'picker' control, that is, 2 list boxes with buttons like << >> < > in between to pick items from one, add to the other? Your question doesn't literally say that, but that is a common widget that doesn't yet come with winforms (they are probably saving it for WPF). If it is what you want please edit so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to handle `SelectedItemChanged` on the first combo box and re-generate the list of Items for the second combo box so that the selected item in the first is excluded.  This should perform alright if you don't have a large number of items.  An additional boundary case to consider:

- If you later change the selection in the first combo box to match what was selected in the second combo box, you might want to clear and reset the second combo box.  You can handle this case in the same `SelectedItemChanged` event handler on the first combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the same index to be selected in the second combobox as you select in the first.

So on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `combobox1` add this code:

`combobox2.SelectedIndex = combobox1.SelectedIndex;`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest but perhaps not the cleanest:

Just repopulate combobox2 based on what's not in combobox1 every time an item is selected in combobox1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contains to check if one have the other and do a loop to check all items.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListBox2.Items.Contains(ListBox1.Items[i]))
                {
                        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                }
            }
```